# Is it possible to make an Asana custom field become a link?

Tags: hyperlink, customization, asana

I would like to have direct links from Asana tasks to our issue tracking system but making creating them easy. The way I envisioned it would be to create an integer custom field and find a way to customize/decorate it so that when the user clicks on it he can immediately open the referenced issue.

For instance, if the field value should be `12345`, the auto generated link would be `https://www.myissuetracking.com/issue/12345`.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be super cool! Unfortunately, this level of UI modification isn't possible yet.

One thing that you *could* do is put something in the task description or (even better) a comment (since comments are immutable except for deletion), something like "Link to https://www.myissuetracking.com/issue/12345" based on the value of the custom field with the id value. If what lands in a comment "looks like" a url, we'll parse it and create the link in Asana.

Comment: This could work for now. I think a smart description change would be better so that if the number in the custom field changes there would be room for updating the link.
But still, not as practical as a link directly from the task list. :)